# Can we add custom validations in formik YupValidationSchema?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

Can we add custom validations in formik YupValidationSchema which I have mentioned below ?

```
YupValidationSchema = () => {
        return Yup.object({
             Email: Yup.string()
            .max(256, "Length exceed 256 chars")
            .matches(EMAIL_REGEXP, "Enter a valid email address")
            .required("Email is required")
})
}
```

I need to add one more validation for the email field like it should accept certain domains

```
let domainVal = companyName.some((val) => email.includes(val));
     if(!domainVal) error('Invalid')
     else  success('Valid');
```

can someone help me how can we add this domain validation code in yupvalidationschema?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`Yup test method`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#schematestname-string-message-string--function--any-test-function-schema) to add a custom validation to your Email

Basic syntax: `.test("test-name", "Error message", function)`

```
return Yup.object({
             Email: Yup.string()
            .max(256, "Length exceed 256 chars")
            .matches(EMAIL_REGEXP, "Enter a valid email address")
            .required("Email is required")
            .test("email-include-domain", "Email Must include domain", (value) => companyNames.some((company) => value.includes(company));
```

Related Stackoverflow Post: [How to get Yup to perform more than one custom validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63769152/how-to-get-yup-to-perform-more-than-one-custom-validation)

Comment: When the field is empty I should get "Email is required" instead I am getting same error "Email Must include domain" ??

Comment: It seems that the order of validation is not guaranteed because Yup operations run in parallel. Check here: https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/256