# Yup - how to check if all arrays are of the same length

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

**TLDR: how do I check that all 3 arrays are of the same length**

I have an optional object **people**, and inside of which is an array **person_name** and each person has likes and dislikes.
How can I check that:

**if** a person was entered **at index 1 for example** he **must** have an array at **index 1** inside of likes and the same for dislikes?

for example this is accepted:

```
{
    person_name: ['foo', 'bar'],
    likes: [['foo stuff'], ['bar stuff']],
    dislikes: [['bar'], ['foo']]
}
```

while these are not accepted:

```
{
    person_name: ['foo', 'bar'],
    likes: [['foo stuff'], ['bar stuff']],
    dislikes: [['bar']]
}
```

AND

```
{
    person_name: ['foo'],
    likes: [['foo stuff'], ['bar stuff']],
    dislikes: [['bar']]
}
```

this is an example of useFormik

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      name: "",
      description: "",
      people: {
        //each index in person_name maps to an array at the same index in likes and dislikes
        person_name: [],
        likes: [[]],
        dislikes: [[]],
      },
    },...
```

Comment: What have you tried? [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple array length

```
if (array.length < n){...}
```

Check child(array inside array)

```
if (array.child.length < n){...}
```

For the `yup` you need to write your validation function, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63769828/8280112)