# Validating non-exclusive regex values with yup

Tags: javascript, formik, yup

How do I create a validator that meets all of the following non-exclusive requirements and displays a different error message for each? I have a Formik form field for phone number. The validation requirement is

1. No alphabetic characters (ASCII alphabets: [A-Za-Z])
2. No period symbol
3. No symbols, (non-period - e.g. ±, $, %, ^, etc.)
4. Only digits, whitespace, and `(,),-`

That requirement is easily handled with the catch-all regex: `/^[\s\d\)\(\-]+$/` using:

```
phoneNo: yup
.string()
.min(6, 'Phone must be at least 6 characters')
.max(35, 'Phone number must be at most 35 characters')
.matches(/^[\s\d\)\(\-]+$/, {  //original matcher
  message: 'Invalid format.',
})
.matches(/\./, {  //my test matcher
  message: 'No period',
}),
```

However, the business wants individual error messages for each validator. So, for 1) no letters, 2) no period, 3) no symbols, and 4) only numbers and `(,),-`. At first I tried chaining multiple `.matches()` as above. If I input `111222.`, the message from the first matcher, `invalid format` would display. However, I expected `No period`. Since `.` is ***non-exclusive*** to both matchers, `.` fails the first check.

I tried both `yup.test()` and `yup.addMethod` but having no experience with yup beyond this, I could not get the syntax right in my head. I've spent hours researching this issue, so it's not for a lack of trying.

P.S. There is no request for validating the actual phone number schema, like `(xxx)xxx-xxxx`, just the values themselves. So a complete phone number regex is not necessary.

UPDATE: I've been trying to modify this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63769152/how-to-get-yup-to-perform-more-than-one-custom-validation) to use `this.matches()`, but I don't understand how to pass in the value to be matched.

As an additional test, I tried using `addMethod()`

```
  yup.addMethod(yup.string, 'noPeriod', function(errorMessage){
   const regexPeriod = /\./;  
   return this.matches(regexPeriod, errorMessage);
  });
```

However, when adding this function to the `.shape()` method

```
.shape({
  phoneNo: yup.string()
  .noPeriod('Period not allowed')
})
```

The TS linter rejects it with `Property 'noPeriod' does not exist on type 'StringSchema<string, AnyObject, string>'.`

Comment: Could you not just move the first matcher to the back so it isn't the first regex that is tested?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with yup, but `.` isn't an accepted character in the `Invalid format.` regex, so it fails there and reports the error message. If you want it to print the `No period` message, you should put that above the `Invalid format.` regex in the chain.

Comment: @caTS I tried that. The order didn't seem to affect the outcome.

Comment: @sloppypasta I tried adding the `.` to the `Invalid format` matcher. Testing with `111111.`, yup doesn't catch the error initially. When I backspace leaving just `111111`, yup then throws a "No period" error which is incorrect behavior. Also, the error is never cleared even if the input is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the challenge you are running into is that `matches` is only checking that the string passed to it actually matches the provided regex. In your case, since the `.` character is not part of your character class in your `Invalid format` regex, it is failing that check and reporting the message.

Since you want to ensure that the provided string does NOT contain a period, you should pass a regex with a negated character class to `matches`. If one of the characters in the negated character class is present, then `matches` will bark with its provided error message.

Another import aspect is that the order of the yup validation chain matters, yup validates each one in order from top to bottom. The first one that fails is the one who's error message gets thrown. You can see this by running the below tests, which all currently pass. Change the order and some of them will start to fail because different messages are thrown.

Sample code with (passing) (jest) tests:

schema.js

```js
import * as yup from 'yup';

const schema = yup.object({
  phoneNo: yup
  .string()
  .min(6, 'Phone must be at least 6 characters')
  .max(35, 'Phone number must be at most 35 characters')
  .matches(/^[^.]*$/, {
    message: 'No period'
  })
  .matches(/^[^!@#$%^&*+=<>:;|~]*$/, {
    message: 'No symbols'
  })
  .matches(/^[\s\d)(-]+$/, {  //original matcher
    message: 'Invalid format.',
  })
});

export default schema;
```

schema.test.js

```js
import { ValidationError } from 'yup';
import schema from './schema';

const testValidation = (obj) => {
  return schema.validateSync(obj);
};

it('catches too few characters', () => {
  const testTooFew = () => {
    testValidation({phoneNo: 'foo'});
  };
  expect(testTooFew).toThrowError(new ValidationError('Phone must be at least 6 characters'));
});

it('catches too many characters', () => {
  const testTooMany = () => {
    testValidation({phoneNo: 'foobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbazfoobarbaz'});
  };
  expect(testTooMany).toThrowError(new ValidationError('Phone number must be at most 35 characters'));
});

it('throws No period error', () => {
  const testPeriod = () => {
    schema.validateSync({phoneNo: '......'});
  };
  expect(testPeriod).toThrow(new ValidationError('No period'));
});

it ('throws No symbols error', () => {
  const testPlus = () => {
    testValidation({phoneNo: '12345+'});
  };
  const testAmpersand = () => {
    testValidation({phoneNo: '12345$'});
  };
  const testPercent = () => {
    testValidation({phoneNo: '12345%'});
  };
  expect(testPlus).toThrow(new ValidationError('No symbols'));
  expect(testAmpersand).toThrow(new ValidationError('No symbols'));
  expect(testPercent).toThrow(new ValidationError('No symbols'));
});

it('allows my allowable characters', () => {
  const allowableObj = {phoneNo: ' \t\n1234567890(-)'};
  expect(testValidation(allowableObj)).toBe(allowableObj);
});
```

Comment: This works as requested. My lack of understanding of how `.matches()` worked is what stumped me. It doesn't seem intuitive. I thought that if you matched a string, like for `.` you would reject that match. I read it as "I found a period in your string, so reject". What you're saying is "`if a regex for not finding a period (meaning it FINDS a period) succeeds`, then it's a match. Throw error message."